# Why isn't the product being added to the user's 'products' using mongodb $push although the post is successful

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add a product but also add the product into a customers account by adding it to the 'products' array in the database.

I am using the customers email as the frontend will only need an admin to put the customers email to find their account.

Below is the request

```
export const addProduct = async (req, res, next)=> {
  try {
    const newProduct = new Product({
    userEmail: req.body.email,
    ...req.body,
  });
    const savedProduct = await newProduct.save();
    await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.body.email}, { $push: { products: newProduct }})
    res.status(201).json(savedProduct);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    next(err);
  }
}
```

Here is the schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const {Schema} = mongoose

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
    },
    fName: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    lName: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    postcode: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    accountNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    sortCode: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    products: {
        type:[],
        required: false,
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

Comment: What _is_ happening? How do you know it's not being added? Are you getting an error message? What is the result of the `findOneAndUpdate()` call?

Comment: im checking the DB to see it not be added to the products array for the individual customer. It's not giving me an error just creating the product and not adding it to the users products

Comment: I'd suggest having the code capture the _response_ from that call and logging it for inspection. It would be helpful to share that here. What would also be helpful would be to provide the specific document of interest along with the `req.body` being supplied to the function. Without that information we're just guessing as to what might be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried addToSet()

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.body.email}, { $addToSet: { products: 
newProduct }})
```

here is link for doc
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#MongooseArray.prototype.addToSet()

Comment: i added another update to it as there was an issue pushing it into the correct customers account:   


`await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: newProduct.userEmail},{ '$addToSet': {products: newProduct }})`